# Creating a "dictionary of sets"

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I need to efficiently store data in something that would resemble a "dictionary of sets" e.g. have a dictionary with multiple (unique) values matching each unique key. The source of my data would be a (not very well) structured XML.

My idea is:
I will look through a number of elements and find keys. If the key does not exist, add it to dictionary, if it already exists, just add a new value in the corresponding key.

And the result would be something like:

```
{
 'key1': {'1484', '1487', 1488', ...}
 'key2': {'1485', '1486', '1489', ...}
 'key3': {'1490', '1491', '1492', ...}
 ...
}
```

I need to add new keys on the go.
I need to push unique values into each set.
I need to be able to iterate through the whole dictionary.

I am not sure if this is even feasible, but if anybody could push me in the right direction, I would be more than thankful.

Comment: what have you done to try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not going to benchmark this but in my experience native dicts are faster

```
store = {}
for key, value in yoursource:
    try:
        store[key].add(value)
    except KeyError:
        store[key] = {value}
```

Comment: Clean, fast solution

Answer (score 13):

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(set)
mydict["key1"] |= {'1484', '1487', '1488'}
```

Iteration is just like the normal dict.

Comment: This won't work, since you are trying to add a set to a set as a member. But sets are unhashable. You probably want something like `|=` instead. Or just add one of the number-words at a time.

Comment: @Paul: Only the keys of a dictionary need to be hashable.

Comment: @martineau as do the elements of a set. The problem here is not related to the enclosing dict, but to the answer trying to stuff a set into a set which happens to be a value in a dict.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, yes I want |=. add is of course for single elements.

Answer (score 3):

Using [dict.setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to create the key if it doesn't exist, and initialising it with an empty [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```python
store = {}
for key, value in yoursource:
    store.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)
```